# The type is not supported by SitecoreIdMapper

Tags: glass-mapper

I'm trying to get children of a specific template under an item using:

```
    [SitecoreQuery("./*[@@templateid='{051E9E07-F488-41EA-A87E-0A92EA32B86B}']", IsRelative = true)]
    public virtual IEnumerable<TopMenuCategory> TopMenuCategories { get; set; }
```

However this seems to be returning an error:

```
The type BrightHorizonsCorp.Models.Navigation.ItemClasses.TopMenuCategory on BrightHorizonsCorp.Models.Navigation.ItemClasses.TopMenuCategory.ID is not supported by SitecoreIdMapper
```

My `TopMenuCategory` class looks like this:

```
public class TopMenuCategory
{
    [SitecoreId]
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    [SitecoreItem]
    public virtual Item SitecoreItem { get; set; }

    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual string Drawer_Title { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Hide_on_Mobile { get; set; }

    [SitecoreQuery("./*[@@templateid='{606CB1C6-35FB-4FFE-8EA6-08EE7D5D46D1}']", IsRelative = true)]
    public virtual IEnumerable<MenuCategory> Categories { get; set; }
    [SitecoreQuery("./*[@@templateid='{57FDD488-21C1-4974-80B3-E507EBB7B27A}']", IsRelative = true)]
    public virtual IEnumerable<MenuLink> Links { get; set; }
    [SitecoreQuery("./*[@@templateid='{39C5DEE0-4CBE-4D7E-B87A-8F8115B60311}']", IsRelative = true)]
    public virtual IEnumerable<MenuLinkWithImage> ImageLinks { get; set; }

    public ShortID ShortId
    {
        get { return SitecoreItem.ID.ToShortID(); }
    }

    public string ID
    {
        get { return Id.ToString().Replace("{", "").Replace("}", ""); }
    }
}
```

I have two questions:

1. What is the cause of this error? How does one resolve it?
2. Is there any alternative to this, where I don't have to hardcode the item ID in the data attribute?

Comment: I would recommend creating a second question for your #2 above, since it's unrelated to the error you received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After resolving other errors and trying trial and error, I found the problem was:

```
public string ID
{
    get { return Id.ToString().Replace("{", "").Replace("}", ""); }
}
```

When I rename this property to something other than "ID", the error does not occur, however it does if I leave it like this. Glass must have been confused or something. **I'm still interested in an alternative** that doesn't require hardcoding the item ID, if anyone has any ideas.

Comment: What are you using this property for, and why do you need it (since you already have the `Id` property)? Also, you can simplify the code by simply returning `Id.ToString("D")`.

Comment: It is an old field I was using before we implemented Glass. It doesn't need to be there as it isn't used anymore. Nice to know about the `ToString` call.